# Could different entities have the same handle?

Tags: field, category

I'm currently setting up a site. One routine operation there is to 1) create a category group and 2) create a 'Categories' field for it to attach to a section later.

Now for safety's sake I'm giving different handle names to the category group and the related field. For example, a category group has a handle called `genre` and the field — `genre_field`, just to ensure that no clashes between them would happen.

But is it actually a possible situation that handles of two different entities (here, fields and cat/groups, but it could be sections and fields as well and so on) could conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, having a field and a category group (or a section and a user group etc) share handles isn't dangerous at all.

Being specific and semantic with handles in general can be a huge boon for keeping things easily memorable and templates and other source code readable, though – so for example you might want to have handles like `genre` (for the category group) and `selectedGenres` (for the categories field), instead of both using `genre`. Though technically, both can be named `genre`, no worries.

Comment: A thank you for a nice and clear answer from the grateful user of your Reasons plugin!